# what does git checkout command do?

Tags: git

I just started learning git and [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCGVk.png) made me confused about what git checkout command does.
I thought it lets you switch between branches am I wrong? What is git checkout doing in the picture?

Comment: Please the documentation first as it's available everywhere with examples

Comment: `git checkout` is kinda like a swiss army knife, so there will be a lot of things a good answer here have to mention and get right. It would probably be better if you read the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or a good tutorial [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-checkout).

Answer (score 1):

checkout is the act of switching between different versions of a target entity. The git checkout command operates upon three distinct entities: files, commits, and branches. In addition to the definition of "checkout" the phrase "checking out" is commonly used to imply the act of executing the git checkout command. git checkout can be used to view old commits. we can perform checkout operations on branches.

It lets you navigate between the branches created by the git branch. Checking out a branch updates the files in the working directory to match the version stored in that branch, and it tells Git to record all new commits on that branch. Think of it as a way to select which line of development you’re working on.

[Refer Here For More](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-checkout#:%7E:text=In%20Git%20terms%2C%20a%20%22checkout,files%2C%20commits%2C%20and%20branches.)